# Deploying code on lambda failed using serverless

Tags: serverless

I was trying to deploy code on lambda using `serverless deploy` and got below error, tried multiple solutions available online but didn't work.

Error -

```
Serverless: Packaging service...

  Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

  The specified bucket does not exist

  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com

  Your Environment Information -----------------------------
     OS:                     darwin
     Node Version:           8.12.0
     Serverless Version:     1.31.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to resolve this issue is -

1. Execute below command to see the lambda information which will also provide the S3 bucket name, region, endpoint info etc but you need only bucket name and region for this case.

`sls info -v`

2. Create the bucket in the intended region.

Done.

Answer (score 0):

When you are deploying your Serverless application it uses the service attribute (defined in your serverless.yaml) as a unique identifier of your application in the CloudFormation.

Said so, you may have some conflict if you change the name of the bucket without removing the stack. Ex:

- You deploy you application with the bucket called myBucket.
- CloudFormation will be created considering this info.
- You change this name to myBucketPlus and try to deploy.
- Serverless will clean the mybucketPlus with the last deploy before pushing the new one.
- But wait! myBucketPlus does not exist.

As you did not describe what exactly you did, I tried to give an example but it could be something else.

Also you could try removing and deploying again.